# Extracting text between two delimiters when the delimiters are in different formats using Python

Tags: python, regex, text, text-mining

I'm a new Python programmer (more experience in R) using Pycharm community edition v2019 2.4, using a laptop running Windows 10.  I'm attempting to extract a block of text between two delimiters which is usually in the following format. (text is between the delimiters but on separate lines)

```
Item 7.
text, text, text, text
text, text, text, text
Item 7A.
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that `Item 7` and `Item 7A` can come in many different formats due to the initial pre-processing of the text files, for example.

```
Item 7.  
text 
Item 7A.
```

or

```
ITEM 7  
text
ITEM 7A.
```

or

```
ITEM 7 
text  
ITEM 7A:
```

or

```
Item 
7
text
Item 
7A.
```

`Item 7` and `Item 7A` can, also appear in larger blocks of text.  This is an issue  beyond my control.

I've examined 100 text files so far and have written the following code.

```
import glob
import os
from os.path import isfile

path = filepath` 
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
     with open(filename) as f:
     data = f.read()

     x = re.findall(r'Item 7(.*?)Item 7A',data, re.DOTALL)
     "".join(x).replace('\n',' ')
     print(x)

     file = open('C:/R_Practice/dale1.txt', 'w')
     file.write(str(x))

     file.close()
```

This deals with some, but not all of the cases, and even then it's not detecting everything. It won't be possible to analyse the full set of text files as there will be close to 250,000 for the full study.  My questions are as follows.

1. Is there a "catch all" code which will search for all occurences of the delimiters, even if parts of the string are on separate lines?
2. Can each individual text block be written to a separate text file on hard drive, once identified?
3. Can a logfile be written showing which text files were not processed because the algorithm "missed" the delimiters owing to formatting issues?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean using a pattern like `^item \d+[A-Z]?[:.]?((?:\r?\n(?!item \d).*)*)` See https://regex101.com/r/dda5rR/1/

Comment: Please reformat your code, it is badly formatted at this time and cannot be processed.

Comment: Please also try to make your example [Minimal and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The fourth bird. I'll try that regex and see what happens.

Comment: The regex you sent works fine if they are on the same line, irrespective of the case, but I will need something that can check the next line as well.  Alsoit doesn't work if there are several spaces between "Item" and "7".

Comment: @Cerberus_64 Pehaps like this having the dot matching a newline? `\bitem \d+[A-Z]?[:.]?(?!\S)(.*?)(?=\bitem \d+[A-Z]?[:.]?|$)`  https://regex101.com/r/4v1xkj/1

Comment: @Cerberus_64 What do you mean by check the next line as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of static space, use `\s` (that means any kind of spaces, including linebreak) between `item` & `7`

```
import glob
import os
from os.path import isfile

path = filepath
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
   with open(filename) as f:
     data = f.read()

     x = re.findall(r'Item\s+7(.*?)Item\s+7A',data, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
     #            here ___^^^   and ___^^^
     "".join(x).replace('\n',' ')
     print(x)

     file = open('C:/R_Practice/dale1.txt', 'w')
     file.write(str(x))

     file.close()
```

Comment: This code seems to catch the majority of the cases I need, but I'm still having problems with setting the case as insensitive and trapping those cases where part of the string is on a separate line.  Will look more into regular expressions and see what happens.

Comment: @Cerberus_64: Add case insensitive flag `re.findall(r'Item\s+7(.*?)Item\s+7A',data, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Adding re.IGNORECASE with the pipe/or symbol seems to work perfectly.  Thanks that was a big help @Toto

Comment: @Cerberus_64: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)